# In DynamoDB, how to fetch some data with multiple conditions(order by and limit)

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling, datamodel, dynamodb-queries

I'd like to get some help to figure out how to fetch some data to meet multiple conditions from the DynamoDB. Following is the situation I've faced.

Data:

> | pk | sk | c1 |
>
> | 1  | 1  | a  |
>
> | 1  | 2  | b  |
>
> | 1  | 3  | b  |
>
> | 1  | 4  | a  |
>
> | 1  | 5  | a  | ...

Application: My app will fetch the last 2 rows(items) with it has to have a specific value of c1. It could express as SQL like:

```
select * from TABLE where pk=1 and c1=b order by sk limit 2;
```

The problem is that DynamoDB is working like fetching the data up to the number 'limit' and then reflecting the conditions. I've got many rows which have same PK, so it is hard to just use pagination method because inefficiency. You know that they will consume capacity unit = my money.

I'm looking for like additional mechanism like Cache, Enhanced Data Model or something to handle this. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is what secondary indexes are for...

Either a local secondary index (LSI), with the same hash key as the table but a sort key of C1.  Or a global secondary index (GSI) with a different hash key, possibly C1 as the hash key.

Instead of querying the table, you query the index.

Note that GSI as basically a separate system maintained DDB table, with their own RCU/WCU and storage costs.

Comment: it doesnt work. I have a query with 3 conditions, limit and order by. I have a GSI on one of the fields which is in the conditions, and a sort key of that GSI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the respond.

If you don't mind can I ask some additionally. How about in case of multiple conditions for c1?

for example:

> | pk | sk | c1 |
>
> | 1 | 1 | a |
>
> | 1 | 2 | b |
>
> | 1 | 3 | c |

`select * from TABLE where pk=1 and c1 in (b,c) order by sk limit 2;`

I'm in trouble this case practically.
If the inverted(GSI, LSI...) index has made using c1, it wouldn't meet the expectation. It because DynamoDB can't use multiple primary key when executing query in my understanding.

my expectation of above case is: getting 2 rows = (1,2,b), (1,3,c)

In DynamoDB, however : 1 row (1,2,b)